# Using canvas drawImage throws an error in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, next.js

I am trying to load a local image onto canvas element but it's throwing an error:

> Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The
> provided value is not of type '(CSSImageValue or HTMLCanvasElement or
> HTMLImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or ImageBitmap or OffscreenCanvas
> or SVGImageElement or VideoFrame)'.

It works fine when I draw or do stuff with canvas window but when I try to import image using `image = Image(gImage.default)` it breaks? I am trying to follow along a tutorial made for react on Next.js, is it something because of it?

My code:

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Image from "next/image";

const Canvas = (props) => {
    const canvasRef = useRef(null)
    // load image
    const gImage = require("../public/map.png")
    const image = Image(gImage.default)
    useEffect(() => {
        const someTry = () => {
        }
        const canvas = canvasRef.current
        const context = canvas.getContext('2d')
        // our first draw
        context.fillStyle = "#000000"
        context.fillRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height)
        console.log(image)
        someTry()

        // const mapImage = document.createElement('img')
        // mapImage.src = '../public/map.png'
        // context.drawImage(image, 0, 0)
        image.onload = () => {
            context.drawImage(image, 0, 0)
        }
    }, [])
    return <canvas ref={canvasRef} {...props} width={288} height={480} />
}

export default Canvas
```

I thought this was something related to `getStaticProps` but when I try to pass image from there it says `Image()` method is not defined, so is there any way around this? And why is it happening?

Comment: Try removing `import Image from "next/image";` from the imports, and moving the `gImage` and `image` variables declarations inside the `useEffect`.

Comment: it works fine now!! but local image imports does not seem to work for some reason

Comment: Try setting the image as `const image = Image()` then set its source with `image.src = "/map.png"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image) constructor you're trying to use is not from `next/image`. You should remove `import Image from "next/image"` from the imports.

You should also move the `image` variable initialisation inside the `useEffect`, and set the image's source to `"/map.png"`.

```js
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";

const Canvas = (props) => {
    const canvasRef = useRef(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        const image = new Image()
        image.src = "/map.png"
        
        const canvas = canvasRef.current
        const context = canvas.getContext('2d')
        context.fillStyle = "#000000"
        context.fillRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height)
       
        image.onload = () => {
            context.drawImage(image, 0, 0)
        }
    }, [])

    return <canvas ref={canvasRef} {...props} width={288} height={480} />
}

export default Canvas
```